# How to add a calendar month to a date?

Tags: numbers

In Numbers, if I have a column for dates, and I want each cell to be one day later than the cell above, I can enter a date in the first cell and then set the next cell to be "cell above plus one". Then I can drag the cell border down to fill the column with increasing consecutive dates.

Is it possible to do this with calendar months? A rough approximation would be to set each cell to be "cell above plus 30," but this would give a different date each month. I want to be able to fill cells with the same date each calendar month. In other words, if a cell contains "7/11/20" I'd like to be able to drag the cell border down to automatically fill the next cell with "7/12/20".

Comment: What did you already try? Did you check the function catalogue for appropriate functions?

Comment: @nohillside The answer to both of your questions is the same: I've tried looking in the function browser for a function which will add a calendar month, but I haven't found one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try formula and get easily what you are looking for.

`EDate, starting row and month =1` (which increase the month when you scroll it)

[image]

**FINAL RESULT WILL BE:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have guessed it from the function's name.